# Using one raster calculator output as input to another raster calculator algorithm with QGIS processing

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, raster-calculator

I am using QGIS 3.16.

How do I call my previous raster calculator output as input to my current raster calculator script?

The below script is what I tried and shows error. I need to use ndvi_result as input in another raster calculator algorithm

```
params = {
            'CELLSIZE': 0,
            'CRS': None,
            'EXPRESSION': '((\"{}@1\" -\"{}@1\") / (\"{}@1\" +\"{}@1\"))>(0.45)'.format(nir.name(), red.name(), nir.name(), red.name()),
            'EXTENT': None,
            'LAYERS': [nir],
            'OUTPUT':  parameters['NDVI'],
        }
        ndvi_result = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', params, context=context)
       
        params = {
            'CELLSIZE': 0,
            'CRS': None,
            'EXPRESSION': '(\"{}@1\" -\"{}@1\") '.format(ndvi_result['OUTPUT'],water_result['OUTPUT']),
            'EXTENT': None,
            'LAYERS': [ndvi],
            'OUTPUT':  parameters['VEG'],
        }
        veg_result = processing.run('qgis:rastercalculator', params, context=context)
```